# Play 2.8.8 Deployment on Heroku crashes while starting the server

Tags: heroku, server, crash, guice, playback

I'm trying to deploy a Scala Play project on Heroku via Heroku CLI.

It works well, but when the server tries to start it crashes with the following error:

```html
2021-08-17T16:47:52.333689+00:00 app[web.1]: at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:91)
2021-08-17T16:47:52.333713+00:00 app[web.1]: at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:306)
2021-08-17T16:47:52.333753+00:00 app[web.1]: at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
2021-08-17T16:47:52.333762+00:00 app[web.1]: at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:168)
2021-08-17T16:47:52.333789+00:00 app[web.1]: at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:39)
2021-08-17T16:47:52.333813+00:00 app[web.1]: at com.google.inject.internal.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:62)
2021-08-17T16:47:52.333838+00:00 app[web.1]: at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.loadEagerSingletons(InternalInjectorCreator.java:213)
2021-08-17T16:47:52.333867+00:00 app[web.1]: at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.injectDynamically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:184)
2021-08-17T16:47:52.333893+00:00 app[web.1]: at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:111)
2021-08-17T16:47:52.333919+00:00 app[web.1]: at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:87)
2021-08-17T16:47:52.333942+00:00 app[web.1]: at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:78)
2021-08-17T16:47:52.333968+00:00 app[web.1]: at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceBuilder.injector(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:200)
2021-08-17T16:47:52.333993+00:00 app[web.1]: at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder.build(GuiceApplicationBuilder.scala:155)
2021-08-17T16:47:52.334018+00:00 app[web.1]: at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationLoader.load(GuiceApplicationLoader.scala:21)
2021-08-17T16:47:52.334042+00:00 app[web.1]: at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.start(ProdServerStart.scala:53)
2021-08-17T16:47:52.334076+00:00 app[web.1]: at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.main(ProdServerStart.scala:29)
2021-08-17T16:47:52.334102+00:00 app[web.1]: at play.core.server.ProdServerStart.main(ProdServerStart.scala)
2021-08-17T16:47:52.408221+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 255
2021-08-17T16:47:52.471552+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-08-17T16:47:52.490499+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-08-17T16:47:58.797308+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `target/universal/stage/bin/bionplaydatawarehouse -Dhttp.port=${PORT}`
2021-08-17T16:48:01.183756+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
2021-08-17T16:48:01.398386+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -XX:+UseContainerSupport -Xmx300m -Xss512k -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
2021-08-17T16:48:06.203049+00:00 app[web.1]: WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
2021-08-17T16:48:06.203069+00:00 app[web.1]: WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$1 (file:/app/target/universal/stage/lib/com.google.inject.guice-4.2.3.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
2021-08-17T16:48:06.203069+00:00 app[web.1]: WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$1
2021-08-17T16:48:06.203070+00:00 app[web.1]: WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
2021-08-17T16:48:06.203076+00:00 app[web.1]: WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
2021-08-17T16:48:15.071607+00:00 app[web.1]: Oops, cannot start the server.
```

The projet parameters are:

- Play 2.8.8
- Scala 2.13.5
- SBT 1.5.0
- Java 11

The project is based on an IntelliJ Ultimate Template.

The Heroku Procfile looks like this:

```
web: target/universal/stage/bin/bionplaydatawarehouse -Dhttp.port=${PORT}
```

The system.properties file looks like this to overwrite the default Java 8 Version:

```
java.runtime.version=11
```

When I change the Java Version the compilation crashes with a Class Cast Exception.

It seems that the Guice DI is the problem or some configuration parameter is missing for the Heroku production invironment because locally the projects works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it!

You need to add the **-Dplay.http.secret.key** argument which value must match your appliaction secret.

Unfortunately this was not part auf the documetation

> web: target/universal/stage/bin/myProject -Dhttp.port=${PORT}
> -Dplay.http.secret.key='mySecret'